# Оборот с «ввиду» — нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

> Возможны резкие коррекции на рынках(,) ввиду раздутости некоторых
> активов(,) и удешевление национальных валют.

Уважаемые филологи, нужны ли запятые в предложении?

Answer (score 1):

Обособление зависит от того, главной или  второстепенной информацией является *ввиду раздутости некоторых активов*. Если главной -- обособлять не надо. Если второстепенной — можно обособить.
Подробнее [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1).

Comment: А как узнать, какая это информация, главная или основная? Это только автор знает или это следует из контекста? Кроме того, именно выделенная информация может быть как очень важной, так и, наоборот, второстепенной. Наверное, это тоже надо учитывать.

Comment: @Sharon насколько я понимаю, в таких случаях именно автор -- своей пунктуацией -- указывает, важное или второстепенное значение имеет информация.

Comment: К сожалению, мы не различаем "важность и второстепенность"  на письме и в устной речи.  Мы видим или слышим просто выделенную информацию, а с помощью знаков автор решает вопрос  о необходимости выделения. И мне кажется, здесь надо учитывать контекст, то есть насколько тема активов была раскрыта раньше.

Answer (score 1):

*Возможны резкие коррекции на рынках, **ввиду раздутости некоторых активов**, и удешевление национальных валют.*

Как уже было сказано, обособление обстоятельственного оборота **факультативное**, то есть это авторский выбор. В то же время выбор автора должен быть обоснованным.

В принципе **структура** предложения допускает оба варианта, но с этой точки зрения оборот лучше **обособить.** Он расположен между двумя однородными сказуемыми, и там удобно выделить его паузами.

С точки зрения **семантики** оборот обособляется, если тема раздутых активов упоминалась в контексте **раньше**, тогда это уточняющая информация.

Если же об этом говорится **впервые**, то оборот лучше не обособлять и включить его в состав основного предложения.

Это как раз те факторы, которые следует учитывать при авторском решении задачи.